# PDO CLASS - Is this technically correct?

Tags: php, class, pdo

I found the following PDO Class at http://culttt.com/2012/10/01/roll-your-own-pdo-php-class/ by Philip Brown.

I am new to Classes. This is working well. Does anyone see anything wrong with it or can it be improved? I want to use it in a large scale application.

```
class Database
{
private $host = DB_HOST;
private $user = DB_USER;
private $pass = DB_PASS;
private $dbname = DB_NAME;

private $dbh;
private $error;

private $stmt;

public function __construct()
    {
    // Set DSN
    $dsn     = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;
    // Set options
    $options = array(
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    );
    // Create a new PDO instanace
    try
        {
        $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
        }
    // Catch any errors
    catch (PDOException $e)
        {
        $this->error = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }


public function query($query)
    {
    $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
    }

public function bind($param, $value, $type = null)
    {
    if (is_null($type))
        {
        switch (true)
        {
            case is_int($value):
                $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                break;
            case is_bool($value):
                $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                break;
            case is_null($value):
                $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                break;
            default:
                $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
        }
        }
    $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
    }


public function execute()
    {
    return $this->stmt->execute();
    }

public function resultset()
    {
    $this->execute();
    return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

public function single()
    {
    $this->execute();
    return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

public function rowCount()
    {
    return $this->stmt->rowCount();
    }

public function lastInsertId()
    {
    return $this->dbh->lastInsertId();
    }

public function beginTransaction()
    {
    return $this->dbh->beginTransaction();
    }

public function endTransaction()
    {
    return $this->dbh->commit();
    }

public function cancelTransaction()
    {
    return $this->dbh->rollBack();
    }


public function debugDumpParams()
    {
    return $this->stmt->debugDumpParams();
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the point of this? Why not just call the PDO class directly?

Comment: The tutorial you followed has no purpose.  For what little functionality it does have, why not simply inherit from PDO in the first place?  I wouldn't use that tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you should stick with the native PDO class. Database class from this tutorial doesn't provide you any extra functionality and actually reduces it. For example

```
public function single()
{
$this->execute();
return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

limits returned data type only to arrays whereas original PDO class has ~8 different fetch styles you can use depending on your taste and needs.

Also I can't see any decent point in the following code

```
public function beginTransaction()
{
return $this->dbh->beginTransaction();
}
```

just wrapper for exactly the same function with same name, again no extra functionality.

Furthermore, this class limits you from creating multiple prepared statements - with original PDO class you can do something like:

```
$stmt1 = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM foo');
$stmt2 = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM bar');
...
$stmtn = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM foobar');
```

You can't do this with class provided in tutorial - statement object is hard-coded as single class variable.

And lastly, I don't really approve function naming for this class. Function name should be like a short descriptions, but names like "single" and "resultset" really do not provide any kind of information what particular function does, returns or how it affects overall state of your program.

To sum it all up, in my opinion it is rather poorly designed class which doesn't have any advantages over native PDO implementation.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly the kind of feedback I was looking for. Just recently started with PDO and still having a hard time grasping classes. Still reasearching on whether I need a Class just for the connection. It would seem if I wanted to use more than one database then I would probably need at least that. Thank you for your responses.

Comment: @Coder what's the relation between need for the more than one database and "at least that"? Aren't you under delusion that you can't use original PDO for the multiple databases as well?

Comment: You can use multiple database connections with PDO, but the Database class provided in this tutorial only can connect with connection parameters defined by DB_* constants. This is yet another limitation when using this class.

Answer (score 0):

> anything wrong with it

Everything. Namely,

```
private $host = DB_HOST;
```

Having a class variable for the DB credentials **makes absolutely no sense.** They are used in constructor only, only once.

```
catch (PDOException $e)
```

Makes very little sense. A caught error nowhere used, which spoils the very idea of exceptions.

the rest of the class just mimic PDO functionality.

**The ONLY** difference from the original PDO is it can let you bind PDO NULLs into DB NULLs automatically. However, I doubt you will ever have an idea to do so.

Thus, like everyone else, I'd suggest you to get rid of this class and this tutorial. **Especially** if you are new to classes. Such an example can spoil your whole experience.